# Efficient way to the find the groups present in a list

Tags: java, list, algorithm, data-structures

There are a few people in a class e.g. [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]. And there are some friends groups e.g. [G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6].

Group G1 = [P1, P2, P3, P4], this says the persons P1, P2, P3, P4 are friends with each other.
Group G2 = [P1, P3, P4] this says P1, P3, and P4 are friends with each other.

This information is given to me as:

1. List of persons belonging to a class.
2. An utility function that returns the list of groups a person belongs to.
   E.g. getGroups(Person P1) returns [G1, G3, G2,..]
3. An utility function that returns the list of persons in a group.
   E.g. getPersons(Group G1) returns [P2, P1, P3,..]
   But I cannot directly access all the groups present, and I don't even know how many groups are present.

What I want:
Given a list of persons [Pi, Pj, Pm, ..., Pn], I want to find out the groups formed by any subset of persons in the list.
Neither the order (of elements) in input nor in the lists returned by utility functions matters.

Eg.
**Information 1** (I cannot iterate over all the persons, but if I have the person's name I can access its data):
`P1 = G1, G2; P2 = G1, G3; P3 = G1; P4 = G1, G2, G3; P5 = G3`
**Information 2** (I cannot iterate over these groups, but if I have group name I can access its data):
`G1 = [P1, P2, P3, P4]; G2 = [P1, P3, P4]; G3 = [P2, P4, P5]`

**Query:** `[P1, P3, P2, P4]`
**Output:** `[G1, G2]` (any order)
**Explanation:**
P1, P2, P3, P4 belongs to group G1.
P1, P3, P4 belongs to group G2.
*Group G3 is not outputted because P5 is not in the input query list.*

Obvious way to solve this is to iterate over each person and each group.

```
personsTracked = []
result = []
for (Person person : persons) {
  personsTracked.add(person) // Using personsTracked to avoid duplicate groups addition to result
  groupsPersonBelongsTo = person.getGroups()
  for (Group group : groupsPersonBelongsTo) {
    if (personsTracked.containsAll(group.getPersons())):
      result.add(group)
  }
}
```

But is there a way to optimise this? Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your #3 should be "A utility function that returns a list of persons in a group."

Comment: You said: "Given a list of persons [Pi, Pj, Pm, ..., Pn], I want to find out all the groups present here." Where is "here?" Do you mean that, given a list of persons, you want to get a list of all the groups those persons represent?

Comment: Do all of the people in a group have to be present in order for the group to be considered present? Or is a group "present" if any one or more of the people from the group is present?

Comment: Re `I think your #3 should be "A utility function that returns a list of persons in a group."` - oops, sorry, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear.
Re `Do you mean that, given a list of persons, you want to get a list of all the groups those persons represent?` - No, I want the groups where all the persons belonging to that group should be present in the input list of persons given.
I've made changes in the actual question too. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Re `Do all of the people in a group have to be present in order for the group to be considered present?` - The order does not matter, if *all* the people are present in the group, we consider it present.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has poor performance because you are using `.containsAll` repeatedly.  This has to look through the entire list each time, to find what is missing.

You can improve performance by creating a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) mapping groups to the count of members.  Create another saying by group, how many times you found a person in that group.  Walk through the people, look at the groups that they are in, and populate both.  Compare the two. Any group the numbers match, then you saw all the members and the group is completely contained in your collection of people.

This algorithm should be linear in the number of times a person in your collection is a member of some group.  Which is required just to find which groups might be included.